# JavaScript - Daterangepicker, isInvalidDate method enabling only one day

Tags: javascript, angular, string, typescript, datepicker

I added daterangepicker (daterangepicker.com) to my project and I want to disable/enable some specific dates. There is an method to do that -> isInvalidDate so I did something like this in options:

```
        isInvalidDate: (date) => {
        for (let i = 0; i < this.periodsArray.length; i++) {
            if (date == Date.parse(this.periodsArray[i])){
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
```

The periodsArray has strings that represents dates in this format ["YYYYMMDD",...] or "YYYYMM" <- this format should enable all days in this month. Before that I've had other if statement:

```
if (date.format('YYYYMMDD') == this.periodsArray[i] || date.format('YYYYMM') == this.periodsArray[i])
```

And this one enabled only one periodsArray[0] date. Can someone help me with that?

Comment: you are comparing all the dates in the to periodsArray just one date, so I guess it will only enable that one day.

Comment: what do You mean just one date? there is 'for' loop to compare every string-date in array

Comment: true, but they are all being compared to one date, the one that was entered into the isInvalidDate function.

Comment: what I suppose to change to do this correctly? When is false then use 'continue' to go to another iteration?

Comment: Yes because you return on every iteration. Try returning only in the end or using continue as you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning on every iteration so it will always return the answer for the first element in the array, instead compare all and return the answer at the end, try something like that:

```
isInvalidDate: (date) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.periodsArray.length; i++) {
        if(date == Date.parse(this.periodsArray[i])){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

this will return false on the first match. saying the date is not invalid = valid, and true if there was no match saying the date is invalid.